# Add value to select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a select that take values from database.

```
<%= select_tag :location, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :country_name), { :class => 'selectpicker' } %>
```

So i get all countries from database.
How i can do for add a custom value(for example Any, with value 0), to this select list taken from database ?
For example now i have:

```
<select>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

and i want get this:

```
<select>
<option value="0">Any</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the either `prompt` or `include_blank` options ([FormOptionsHelper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper)) as follows:

```
<%= select_tag :location, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :country_name), :prompt => 'Any', :class => 'selectpicker' %>
```

Comment: It say: wrong number of arguments (4 for 3), anyway i don't want only show "Any", but also assign a value to this prompt...example Any have value 0.

Comment: @Richard, please see the updated answer that fixes the wrong number of arguments.  When I tested this I was using `f.select` which eventually led to copy/paste error. Why do you need this value to be zero, do you want it to be stored in db?

Comment: No, i don't store in db...but i want know if the user have choice Any(it's a search form).

Comment: Now give me in params:  "location"=>"", (when i choice any).

Comment: You probably want to add `presence` validation on that field?